# gnuplot output of a pipe

Tags: pipe, gnuplot

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17543386/3134778) I tried to pipe output to gnuplot and then plot it.

My pipe is:

```
cat file.txt |
grep CU | 
perl -e 'while(<>){print +(split)[3], "\n"}' | 
gnuplot file.gp
```

Where file.gp contains the following:

```
set terminal dumb
plot '<perl' using 1
```

The output of the pipe is:

```
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-77.8333771886
-7.78333787544e+01
-7.78333787544e+01
```

Now I got this error:

```
plot '<perl' using 1
               ^
"file.gp", line 3: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot '<perl' using 1
                ^
"file.gp", line 3: x range is invalid
```

Piping the output into a file and then doing `gnuplot file.gp` with `file.gp` modified to contain the filename works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My internet connection went down when I was about to post this question, so I had to try some more things on my own and eventually figured out how to do it. But since I had already written the question I feel I might as well share my new-found knowledge. I also encourage other answers that provide more insight.

My solution was to change `file.gp` to

```
set terminal dumb
plot '<cat' using 1
```

and then adjust the pipe chain like this

```
cat file.txt |
grep CU | #I put an identifier in the file 
perl -ne 'print +(split)[3], "\n"' | #strip the identifier
cat | #this makes gnuplot accept the output from the pipe
gnuplot file.gp
```